# Sourcing (just-some-lines) from .vim file

Tags: vim

The title is pretty much self-explanatory; is there a way to just source a couple of selected lines from a .vim file, instead of copying it to a new buffer, saving it, ... etc.

I don't want to (after writing it in a file) rewriting it in a command line, but just select it and source it. Unfortunatelly, "source" doesn't work on a range.

Bright ideas welcomed :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom command combined with `g//`

```
command! -range=% RSource <line1>,<line2>g/./exe getline('.')
```

Then select you're code, hit `:` and type `RSource` (so the command line should look like `:'<,'>RSource`).